# Re-entry to Italy after expired Permesso di Soggiorno but valid multiple entry student visa

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, italy, permesso-di-soggiorno

I hold a Type D Student Visa in Italy with multiple entry until 24 Nov.
Italy issued my Permesso di Soggiorno with expiry of my original leaving date on 31 Oct.
However, I've extended my stay in Italy until 24 Nov (same last day as my visa) but I will travel out of Italy for 2 weeks to the UK before that on 29 Oct and back 12 Nov.

Will I be allowed re-entry as long as my multiple entry student visa is still valid even if my PdS is expired upon return?

Thanks in advance